# Refresh dataTable with hml data source using ajax in Client-side

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am using a bootsrap dataTable with html data Source. Iam trying to refresh it every 30 seconds with ajax call.
The problem is that search option and keys not working after the refresh call.

This is my table :

```
<table id="datatable-buttons">
   <thead>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tbody">
      <td onClick="funcion1();">1</td>
      <td onClick="funcion2();">TEST</td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This my javascript code :

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var method = "GET";
      var url = "RefreshTable.php";
      var asynchronous = true ;
      ajax.open(method,url,asynchronous);
      ajax.send();
      ajax.onreadystatechange  = function()
      {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
           document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML = this.responseText ;
        }
      }
 }, 30000);

 // DataTable 
var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({

                "paging":   false,
                "ordering": false,
                keys : true ,
                 keys: {
                       keys: [ 13 /* ENTER */, 38 /* UP */, 40 /* DOWN */ ]
                       },
                stateSave: true,]
            });
```

This is RefreshTable.php

```
      <td onClick="funcion1();">2</td>
      <td onClick="funcion2();">TEST2</td>
```

I didn't understand why search function didn't work after the refresh.

Comment: You need to recreate the table after each "refresh". A better alternative is using DT ajax and `table.ajax.reload()`..

Comment: Thanks but how could I load data using ajax ?

Comment: [**table.ajax.reload()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) ...

Comment: How to change html data to json ?

Comment: You can change source to json like this: 
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );


https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax